# Find $f(x)$ such that $f(\frac{3}{x})+f(\frac{x}{2})=\frac{9}{x^2}+\frac{x^2}{4}-2$

Tags: calculus, functions

How to find $f(x)$ from below relation ?
$$f\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)+f\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{9}{x^2}+\frac{x^2}{4}-2$$ I have two question about this .I find $f(x)=x^2-1$  that work fine ,but
$\\(1)$ how can be sure that there is no other solutions ?

$\\(2)$ How can find $f(x)$ in general ?

Comment: You have to specify the domain. Otherwise there is a problem when $x=0.$

Comment: An explicit example of another solution is $f(x) = (3/2) x^{-2} - 1$.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier if you put $g(x) =f(x)-x^2+1$. Then your equation became: $$ g\Big({3\over x}\Big) +g\Big({x\over 2}\Big) =0$$

Comment: @JohnWatson: Also $g\left(\sqrt{\dfrac32}x \right)=h(x)$ gives us a more symmetric version of this equation $$h\left(x\right)+h\left(\dfrac 1x\right)=0.$$

Answer (score 7):

If $f$ is analytic, we can expand it in a Laurant Series:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nx^n.$$

Then $f(3/x)+f(x/2)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty 3^na_nx^{-n}+2^{-n}a_nx^n.$

Your functional equation implies that for $n\notin (-2,2,0)$:

$$3^{-n}a_{-n}+2^{-n}a_n=0,$$

You can also work out the coefficients $a_0,a_{\pm 2}$:

$2a_0=-2 \Rightarrow a_0=-1$

$$3^{-2}a_{-2}+2^{-2}a_2=1/4$$
$$3^{2}a_{2}+2^{2}a_{-2}=9,$$

which are the same equation, so $a_2=1-4a_{-2}/9$. So even without the rest of the $a_i$, you can still form an infinite family of solutions:

$$f(x)=\frac{c}{x^2}+(1-4c/9)x^2-1.$$